# How to increase the connection limit for the Google Cloud SQL Postgres database?

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

The number of connections for Google Cloud SQL PostgreSQL databases is relatively low. Depending on the plan this is somewhere between 25 and 500, while the limit for MySQL in Google Cloud SQL is between 250 and 4000, reaching 4000 very quickly.

We currently have a number of trial instances for different customers running on Kubernetes and backed by the same Google Cloud SQL Postgres server. Each instance uses a separate set of database, roles and connections (one per service). We've already reached the limit of connections for our plan (50) and we're not even close to getting to the memory or cpu limits. Connection pooling seems not to be an option, because the connections are with different users.
I'm wondering now why the limit is so low and if there's a way to increase the limit without having to upgrade to a more expensive plan.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

It looks like google just released this as a beta feature.
When creating or editing a database instance, you can add a flag called `max_connections`, where you can enter a new limit between 14 and 262143 connections.

[image: gcp cloud sql connection limit flag]

Answer (score 32):

As of 2024 the number of connections can be changed with a `max_connections` flag.

Its default value depends on the amount of RAM and as of Feb 2024 are the following:

```
Memory size, in GB  | Maximum concurrent connections
--------------------+-------------------------------
~0.5 (tiny)         | 25
~1.7 (small)        | 50
3.75 up to 6        | 100
6 up to 7.5         | 200
7.5 up to 15        | 400
15 up to 30         | 500
30 up to 60         | 600
60 up to 120        | 800
120 and above       | 100
```

The most up-to-date version of this table is in the official docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/flags#postgres-m).

Comment: This should be put on official documentation. To avoid losing more time figuring out this after the next 2 weeks of memory, the error was "FATAL:  remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections".

Comment: Google announced a connection limit increase: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37271935#comment99

Comment: A small update, the amount of connections has been increased: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/quotas#cloud-sql-for-postgresql-connection-limits

Answer (score 4):

For the Terraform gang, you can update the parameter using `database_flags`:

```
resource "google_sql_database_instance" "main" {
  name             = "main-instance"
  database_version = "POSTGRES_14"
  region           = "us-central1"

  settings {
    tier = "db-f1-micro"

    database_flags {
      name  = "max_connections"
      value = 100
    }
  }
}
```

Note that at the time of writing the `db-f1-micro` default `max_connections` is 25, refs https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/flags#postgres-m